# selecting all pairs of words in a string in bash

Tags: regex, bash

How can one select all pairs of subsequent words in a text in bash?

For example, the string `test tet test tezt` should be converted to

```
test tet
tet test
test tezt
```

I've tried using regular expressions, but that only yields half the pairs since the matcher starts where it's left off, e.g. `echo "test tet test tezt" | grep -Po '[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+'`
 only yields the first and the third output, not the second.

Please note: the original string is guaranteed to contain only spaces and letters

Edit: I need a solution that I can afterwards pipeline into another program.

Comment: What do you know about this string? Newline-separated? Whitespace-separated _only_? ...?

Comment: ...also, what should happen if the string contains non-alpha content? Your regex implies that numbers should be excluded; is that a true requirement?

Comment: just words and (possibly multiple) spaces inbetween them on each line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
s='test tet test tezt'
awk -v RS=' ' 'NR>1{print p, $1} {p=$1}' <<< "$s"
test tet
tet test
test tezt
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `awk -v RS=' ' 'p{print p, $1} {p=$1}' <<< "$s"`

Answer (score 3):

Use an array of words:

```
#!/bin/bash
string='test tet test tezt'
read -a words -d '' <<< "$string"
for (( i=1; i<${#words[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "${words[i-1]} ${words[i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The pure (POSIX, Bourne) shell solution without unportable bashisms like `<<<` or arrays or `(( ))` and without expensive forks to external programs -- works in *any* modern shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

s='test tet test tezt'
set -- $s
while test $# -gt 1; do
   printf '%s %s\n' $1 $2
   shift
done
```

Note how easily the shell's word splitting with `set` works and the shifting takes care of iterating the next pair into place!

Comment: That is vulnerable to pathname expansion too if the string contains `*` or other glob-chars

Comment: Glenn Jackman is correct. And why care about unportability anyways? the question is clearly tagged bash.

Comment: @glennjackman: The OP stated *Please note: the original string is guaranteed to contain only spaces and letters*.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Because portability is the hallmark of proper programming. You can't start teaching users too early that *All the world's a bash/Linux/i86* is going to bite them soon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let file ff contain "test tet test tezt"

```
armathew@3NJ2VQ1 /cygdrive/d
$ list=(`cat ff`); elems=`cat ff | wc -w`; for ((i = 0; i < $[ $elems - 1 ]; i++)); do echo ${list[$i]} ${list[$i + 1]}; done;

test tet
tet test
test tezt
```

But even i prefer anubhava's solution :-)

Comment: Useless use of cat; `wc -w < ff`. But forking/execing three processes for such a simple task?

Comment: Yes, i agree it is bad :-)